# AlwaysRunning IIS application does not restart after bin change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have a asp.net (4.5) application running in IIS 8.5.  This is a web service application, and is set to be always running.  After a bin change (such as a VS build) the application is not automatically restarting.  This used to work, but no longer does.

The app pool `autoStart` is set to true.  Start mode is set to `AlwaysRunning`.
The website itself has `preloadEnabled` set to true.

My application appears to be shutting down gracefully.  I've logged the `Application_End` event and the shut down reason is a bin change.  Nothing looks like it is crashing.  But the app simply does not start back up until I hit the url.

I've put logging in the `Application_Start()` and it is never hit.  The w3p process in windows is still there, but it does not consume any resources until the page is manually hit the URL.  If I attach a debugger to the process, there is no activity. Once a URL is hit, the application starts up normally without exceptions.

I've created a new app pool and website pointing to the same application, with the same settings and that did not work.

I've created a brand new asp.net project and using the same IIS, created a new app pool and website, and that empty website does auto restart when I build it to make a bin change.  The problem follows the application to another host.  The problem must be with the application but I can't think of what to look at next.

Any ideas?

Comment: IIS has a lazy initializer, when application dies ... will wait for requests to hit the server before application start up again. You will need a workaround if you want your application to be up and running immediately after restart ..

Comment: @EmmanuelN, I'm not sure that is the case when autoStart and AlwaysRunning are set.  At any rate, I can get another application to auto start after a visual studio build using the same IIS settings.  You may be thinking of an OnDemand application.

Comment: Did you specify perload enabled=true at application level from IIS ?

Comment: @Hakunamatata yes, thank you.  Specified that in my post. :)

Comment: Could you check that *application initialization* is installed using *Server Manager*. By default it is not installed but you can configure it using *inetmgr* and these settings will be ignored

Comment: @CyrilDurand Yes, going to the web platform installer in IIS shows that IIS: Application Initialization is installed.  I believe if it was not, my empty test application would not work.